# Apple Development/Distribution certificates among individual account developers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

I have been search all over the place for a proper answer about handling certificates. Imagine the following account.

**Joe** has an Individual Apple Account. But he cant code at all. He just publishes the app and calls it his.

**Bob** also has an Individual Apple Account. Bob is an expert at coding an is being paid by Joe to develop his first iOS app. The app includes PUSH notification.

What should Joe do so that Bob can develop on his own machine and test everything with his own device?

The steps that I think they should do so far:
Joe adds Bob's device UUID into his apple member page.

Joe create the cert on his machine and export the p12 which includes his private key?

Joe also downloads the provisioning profile from the member page?

Joe emails the p12 with password and provisioning profile to Bob?

Bob double clicks the p12 and provisioning profile to start working?

Would this work or is there a better way do this?

Think individual account holders hiring other individual devs to build app freelance.

Any input is appreciated.

THank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no push notifications were involved, there would be no need for Joe to send Bob anything (except a spec). Bob writes the code and tests it under his own account. In fact, it would be Bob who would put Joe's device onto his own list so as to be able to send Joe Ad Hoc test builds.

However, with push notifications in the picture, it will be a lot easier if Joe converts his account to an Organization account so that he can use team management features. It costs no more than the account he has now, but allows him to sell the app and receive the money while bringing Bob onto his team to work on the app. The scenario will then be very much as you describe.

Comment: Fair point.... Woudnt converting to org account require Joe to submit company documents. The obstacle here is Joe is a start up and doesnt really have everything in place yet. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Ok... so what I finally did was... I mean.. what Bob did was... Bob just build the app with his own bundle ID and his own apple ID and even his own firebase instance. When delivering to customer just swap everything to the Joes bundle ID and so on. So thanks to mat for suggesting it and it turning out to be the solution.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that Apple is requiring small companies to incorporate to be able to add a single developer to the account. 