# "None of your accounts are a member of XXXXX" trying to set an app group

Tags: ios, xcode

I've developed an app for a customer who has their own Apple account and profiles etc. 
They have given me their development profiles and dev keychain certificate and want me to deliver the app to them signed with their dev profiles which they will then replace with app store distribution profiles.

I'm having a problem adding an app group to the capabilities. When I click on the + button to add an app group I get the following error:

[image]

This is the signing settings. When their developer provisioning profile was imported as the signing profile XCode set the Team to "Unknown Name (XXXXX)" so it must have pulled that team name from the profile.

[image]

In XCode's accounts I only have my own Apple IDs added, I don't have their Apple ID added (its not possible to without knowing their password though?, something I won't get). I presume this might be why I am getting that error code?

Is there anyway of adding the group id to the project without having to add their Apple ID to XCode's account section?

Answer (score 2):

> They have given me their development profiles and dev keychain certificate and want me to deliver the app to them signed with their dev profiles which they will then replace with app store distribution profiles

That whole approach is mistaken (as you now know). They have two choices:

- You can just develop the app under your own banner, making all your own profiles as needed, and they can make all the necessary substitutions and other changes at their end when they have the code. Or:
- They must make you formally a member of their team (e.g. an [Admin](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)), at least while you're working on the app.

Comment: Compare my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40668605/341994 Indeed, your question is near duplicate of that one.

Comment: If the app were not using groups (or push as in the other question) would this approach work then? What is it about push for example that prevents it from working? (Provided that push entitlements are added to the app id, and profiles etc.)

Comment: There's just a mismatch between your apple ID and the stuff you got from the customer, because (as I said) you are not on their team. So either do you do it all on your own bat and ignore the stuff they gave you, because you are, after all, a member of your own team, or they make you a member of their team.